# fullcalendar.io dayClick event not working I spent a lot of time on it verify jquery version supported how to fix it

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

These is my script code to initialize fullcalendar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        selectable: true,
        dayClick: function(date) {
            alert(date.format());
        }
       });
     });
</script>
```

[image]

These are my script files I used fullcalendar version 3 which uses jQuery v3.3.1
but due to my theme and other dependencies I used jQuery v2.2.4 it fine because on fullcalendar.io support section it is mention such as 
[image]

After follow all these above point fullcalendar dayClick event doesn't work

Comment: any errors in your console when you load the page, or try to click on a day? Do all the scripts load correctly (check your network tools as the page is first loaded and see that they all return 200 OK statuses). Try creating a minimal example by removing all the other scripts until you just have jQuery, moment and fullCalendar left, and then seeing if it works. Then add the other elements back in again until it stops working. Then you'll know where the real issue is.

Comment: Using the script versions you've stated, and with nothing else involved, your code will work fine. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/31/ . P.S. you don't need `selectable: true` in order for `dayClick` to work - the `selectable` option is used in conjunction with the `select` callback instead - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting